# Quickfix - Tag not defined for this message type in groups

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a quickfix issue where the quickfix engine is sending back a Reject message of "Tag not defined for this message type" in reference to tag 22 (SecuritySourceID)

In the inbound fix message this is a sample message:

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=9215|35=y|49=TULLETT|56=ZTEST1|34=12|52=20190220-10:44:17.588|320=ROGERSLReq1288|322=FIXT.1.1:TULLETT->ZTEST1ROGERSLReq1288|560=0|393=16489|893=N|146=50|55=LLOYDS 7.754 21/49 CSH|48=XS0109139344CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0109139344|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.754000187|947=GBP|541=20210531-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLOYDS 7.375 23/49 CSH|48=XS0083932144CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0083932144|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.375|947=GBP|541=20230210-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLOYDS 8 09/23  CSH|48=XS0079927850CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0079927850|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=8|947=GBP|541=20230929-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLOYDS 7.881 12/31 CSH|48=GB0058327924CB|22=8|454=1|455=GB0058327924|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.881000042|947=GBP|541=20311209-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLOYDS 13 29/49 CSH|48=XS0408620721CSH|22=8|454=1|455=XS0408620721|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=13|947=GBP|541=20490122-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLOYDS 7.834 12/15 CSH|48=XS0107228024CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0107228024|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.834000111|947=GBP|541=20491229-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=LLYDIN 6.875 15/25  CSH|48=XS0205875049CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0205875049|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.875|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED  LLYDIN 7.421 06/17 CSH|48=XXXEG5690920CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0307055995|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.421|947=GBP|541=20170621-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MET 5.375 12/09/24 CSH|48=XS0207636712CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0207636712|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.375|947=GBP|470=US|541=20241209-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED - MONTE 5.75 09/16  CSH|48=XS0255817685CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0255817685|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.75|947=GBP|470=IT|541=20160930-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MQB 6.177 04/20 CSH|48=XS0201559811CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0201559811|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.177000046|947=GBP|470=AU|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED  MUFG 6.299 01/17 CSH|48=XS0282533115CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0282533115|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.298999786|947=GBP|470=KY|541=20170125-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NAB 5.62 09/18 CSH|48=XS0177395901CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0177395901|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.619999886|947=GBP|470=US|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NDASS 6.25 07/14  CSH|48=XS0151270310CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0151270310|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.25|947=GBP|470=FI|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED - NRKLN 5.75 12-17 CSH|48=XS0143152337CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0143152337|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.75|947=GBP|541=20120227-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NRKLN 9.375 10/21 CSH|48=XS0070077010CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0070077010|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=9.375|947=GBP|541=20211017-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NRKLN 6.75 24/49  CSH|48=XS0098556961CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0098556961|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.75|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NRKLN 8.399 09/15 CSH|48=XS0117031194CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0117031194|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=8.399000168|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NRKLN 7.053 09/27 CSH|48=XS0152710439CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0152710439|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.052999973|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED  NRKLN 6.8509 07/16 CSH|48=XS0259175536CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0259175536|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.850900173|947=GBP|470=LU|541=20160704-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NWIDE 7.859 30/49 CSH|48=GB0001777886CB|22=8|454=1|455=GB0001777886|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.859000206|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NWIDE 5.769 02/26 CSH|48=XS0184519139CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0184519139|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.769000053|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=NWIDE 7.971 15/49 CSH|48=GB0001777449CB|22=8|454=1|455=GB0001777449|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.971|947=GBP|541=20490929-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=OLDMUT 6.376 03/20 CSH|48=XS0215556142CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0215556142|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.375999928|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=PEALLN 7.25 21/49 CSH|48=XS0133173137CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0133173137|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.25|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=PEALLN 6.5864 04/16 CSH|48=XS0235245205CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0235245205|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.586400032|947=GBP|541=20160411-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=PRUFIN 6.875 01/23 CSH|48=XS0083544212CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0083544212|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.875|947=GBP|541=20230120-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=PRUFIN 5.875 05/29 CSH|48=XS0096874671CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0096874671|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.875|947=GBP|541=20290511-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=PRUFIN 6.125 12/31 CSH|48=XS0140198044CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0140198044|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.125|947=GBP|541=20311219-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED - QBEAU 6.125 09/15 CSH|48=NEWISSUEQBE|22=8|454=1|455=XS0454936013|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.125|947=GBP|470=AU|541=20150928-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=QBEAU 6.857 07/16 CSH|48=XS0261573587CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0261573587|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.856999874|947=GBP|541=20160718-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RABOBK 5.556 19/49 CSH|48=XS0203782551CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0203782551|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.556000233|947=GBP|470=US|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 7.387 10/49 CSH|48=XS0121856859CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0121856859|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.387000084|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 7.375 10/49  CSH|48=XS0116447599CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0116447599|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.375|947=GBP|541=20100831-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 8.162 10/12 CSH|48=XS0323839042CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0323839042|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=8.162|947=GBP|541=20121005-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 6.25 12/12  CSH|48=XS0137784426CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0137784426|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.25|947=GBP|541=20121217-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 6 14/49  CSH|48=XS0193721544CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0193721544|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6|947=GBP|541=20140901-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 7.625 10/49  CSH|48=XS0102493508CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0102493508|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.625|947=GBP|541=20150121-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 5.125 16/49  CSH|48=XS0164828385CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0164828385|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.125|947=GBP|541=20160314-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED - RBS 5.6457 06/17 CSH|48=XS0277453774CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0277453774|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.645699978|947=GBP|541=20170608-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 9.5 18/49 CSH|48=XS0045071932CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0045071932|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=9.5|947=GBP|541=20180812-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 5.5 12/19  CSH|48=XS0206633082CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0206633082|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.5|947=GBP|470=DE|541=20191203-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 6.2 03/22  CSH|48=XS0144810529CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0144810529|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.199999809|947=GBP|541=20220322-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 7.125 10/22  CSH|48=XS0102493680CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0102493680|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=7.125|947=GBP|541=20221005-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 5.625 09/26  CSH|48=XS0154144132CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0154144132|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.625|947=GBP|541=20260916-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RBS 5.625 32/49  CSH|48=XS0138939854CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0138939854|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=5.625|947=GBP|541=20320607-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=MATURED  RLMI 6.125 12/15 CSH|48=XS0236968946CSH|22=8|454=1|455=XS0236968946|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.125|947=GBP|541=20151215-00:00:00|1173=2|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RSA 8.5 12/14 CSH|48=XS0197028714CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0197028714|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=8.5|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RSA 6.701 12/17 CSH|48=XS0254219735CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0254219735|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=6.701000214|947=GBP|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|55=RSA 9.375 05/19 CSH|48=XS0429467961CB|22=8|454=1|455=XS0429467961|456=4|167=CORP|762=NONE|223=9.375|947=GBP|541=20390520-00:00:00|1173=11|423=1|562=0.5|20539=TSFI|20537=0|20538=0|10=192|
```

In my dictionary I have the following created for the message

Message:

```
<message name="SecurityList" msgtype="y" msgcat="app">
<component name="ApplicationSequenceControl" required="N"/>
<field name="SecurityReqID" required="N"/>
<field name="SecurityRequestResult" required="N"/>
<field name="SecurityResponseID" required="N"/>
<field name="TotNoRelatedSym" required="N"/>
<field name="LastFragment" required="N"/>
<component name="NoRelatedSym" required="N"/>
</message>
```

Components:

```
<component name="NoRelatedSym">
<group name="NoRelatedSym" required="N">
    <field name="Symbol" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityID" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
    <component name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityType" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecuritySubType" required="N"/>
    <field name="PeriodCode" required="N"/>
    <field name="Seniority" required="N"/>
    <field name="Issuer" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityDesc" required="N"/>
    <field name="ISDADefinition" required="N"/>
    <field name="MarketSegmentID" required="N"/>
    <field name="ExternalLineRef" required="N"/>
    <field name="GTNID" required="N"/>
    <field name="GTNSubID" required="N"/>
    <field name="Ref Ob ISIN" required="N"/>
    <field name="PriceType" required="N"/>
    <field name="CFICode" required="N"/>
    <field name="CouponRate" required="N"/>
    <field name="StrikeCurrency" required="N"/>
    <field name="CountryOfIssue" required="N"/>
    <field name="MDSubBookType" required="N"/>
    <field name="MinTradeVol" required="N"/>
    <field name="MaturityDate" required="N"/>
    <component name="NoUnderlyings" required="N"/>
</group>
</component>

<component name="NoSecurityAltID">
        <group name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N">
        <field name="SecurityAltID" required="N"/>
        <field name="SecurityAltIDSource" required="N"/>
        </group>
</component>

<component name="NoUnderlyings">
        <group name="NoUnderlyings" required="N">
        <field name="UnderlyingSymbol" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingSecurityType" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingSecurityID" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingSecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
        <component name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingCFICode" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingCreditRating" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingCountryOfIssue" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingStrikeCurrency" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingCouponRate" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingIssuer" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingSecurityDesc" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingSeniority" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingMaturityDate" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingPriceType" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingPeriodCode" required="N"/>
        <field name="UnderlyingISDADefinition" required="N"/>
        </group>
</component>

<component name="NoUnderlyingSecurityAltID">
        <group name="NoUnderlyingSecurityAltID" required="N">

            <field name="UnderlyingSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
            <field name="UnderlyingSecurityAltIDSource" required="N"/>
            </group>
</component>
<component name="NoSecurityAltID">
        <group name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N">
        <field name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
        <field name="SecurityAltID" required="N"/>
        <field name="SecurityAltIDSource" required="N"/>
        </group>
</component>
```

And the session with enabling datadictionary and pointed to FIX50SP2

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=Y
FileLogPath=./logs
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
CheckLatency=N
MaxLatency=240

[SESSION]
FileStorePath=./sessions
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
UseDataDictionary=Y
DefaultApplVerID=9
TransportDataDictionary=./data/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=./data/FIX50SP2.xml
```

Is there any issues with the dictionary or settings i have that is kicking back this reject message? or is there some issue with python quickfix port for grouping?

**Edit**
When i change the NoRelatedSym component and remove the outer group like this

```
<component name="NoRelatedSym">
    <field name="Symbol" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityID" required="N"/>
    <field name="SecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
    <component name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
</component>
```

then the quickfix engine will generate

> Tag appears more than once

Comment: I can only assume that something else is incorrect in your 146/NoRelatedSym group definition.  If your message contains a field in that group that is not in your DD definition for that group, the parser will prematurely end the group and screw up reading anything after that.  I suggest you step through the first couple of 146 groups and make sure all the fields are in your DD and in the same order.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier

Odd thing is, when I change the component for NoRelatedSym and I remove the group like below:

`<component name="NoRelatedSym">
 <field name="Symbol" required="N"/>
 <field name="SecurityID" required="N"/>
 <field name="SecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
    <component name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N"/>
</component> `

then i get the reject message of Tag appears more than once, but once i add the group it gives me tag not defined

Comment: I stand by my recommendation as the best way to proceed.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I was able to solve the issue. It seems the Provider changed the tag for MarketSegmentID from tag 1300 to tag 20539, after changing that field. It looks good now. Do you know if its possible to have multiple tags point to the same name?

Comment: I don't know for sure.  I would need to dig into the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was due to a tag change to MarketSegmentID, the standard tag value for this in FIX5.0SP2 is 1300, but provider changed it to a custom tag of 20539, which broke the nested group. Odd that quickfix doesnt pinpoint the error to that tag but instead defaults it to the top level SecurityIDSource tag

Comment: Ugh, that's so weird.  Counterparties do weird things.  :)  Glad you solved it!